# React: enable a dropdown if the value of other dropdown is initially rendered

Tags: reactjs

I have this two drop downs in my form. second dropdown is disabled unless a specific value is selected in first dropdown.

Let's say that it will be enable if last choice of the first dropdown is selected.
However, the problem is that: **my code only works if the value of the dropdown is changed from others to that desired one . When the desired choice is initial rendered, the second dropdown is not enabled(which it should)**

`What I have tried`: since i wanted the second dropdown to also be enabled if the last value of first drop down is initially render, i tried calling a `setState` in `componentWillMount()` since it happens before initial render. However, since the logic of determining if the second dropdown should be enabled is based on the dropdnw's value(`dropdown_a_id`). It only happens in `handleChange()`,which is invoked after `componentWillMount()`, so during `componentWillMount()`
, the `dropdown_a_id` is `-1`. I also though of `ComponentWillUpdate()`, however, according to react's document, we should not call setState in this event.

What I need help with: I am trying to find the way to enable my second dropdown if the specific value of first dropdown is initially rendered.
I believe there should be a life cycle event handles that, but I don't know which one in this particular case.

```
export default class MyForm extends ApplicationComponent{
   constructor(){
       super()

       this.state = {
         formData: {
           dropdown_a__id: -1,
           dropdown_b_id: -1
         },
         firstDropdown: [],
         secondDropdown: [],
         disableTheDropDown: true
       }
   }

   getFirstDropDownData() {
       ajax({
          url: `someURL`,
          dataType: 'json',
          success: data => {
            this.setState({
               firstDropdown: data
            });
          },
          error: () => {
            console.log("Error")
          }
       })
   }

   getSecondDropDownData() {
       ajax({
          url: `someURL`,
          dataType: 'json',
          success: data => {
            this.setState({
               secondDropdown: data
            });
          },
          error: () => {
            console.log("Error")
          }
       })
   }

   componentWillMount() {
      this.getFirstDropDownData();
      this.getSecondDropDownData();
   }

   getFormData(form_id){
      ajax({
          url: `someURL/${form_id}.json`,
          dataType: 'json',
          success: data => {
            this.setState({
               formData: data
            });
          },
          error: () => {
            console.log("Error")
          }
       })
   }

   compionentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
      if(this.props.form_id !== nextProps.form_id){
        this.getFormData(nextProps.form_id)
      }
   }

   handleChange(e) {  
     let newForm = {formData: this.state.formData}

     newForm = _.merge(newForm.formData, {[e.target.name]: e.target.value})

     let isLastChoiceSelected = newForm.dropdown_a__id == 9 ? false : true

     this.setState({
       denail: newDenial,
       disableNoRecordExistReason: DoesReasonExist
     })
   }

   render(){
      return(
         //Render the form
      )
   }
```

Comment: You care not updating state property `disableTheDropDown` onmount, you are only updating it on handleChange

Comment: that's the problem. I wanted to enable the second drop down before render but the logic of determining it is inside of handleChange, which is after render.

Comment: So right after `this.getFormData(nextProps.form_id)` check if last option of first select box is chosen, and change state disableTheDropDown to false

Comment: I have tried that before too. It works oddly. So if I open my form the first time, the second drop down is still disabled. However, if I close my form and reopen it again, it is then enabled. Is it because since setState is asynchronous, the first time I open the form , the both setState are executed so the condition checvk of second setState failed?

Comment: getFormData, getSecondDropDownData,getFirstDropDownData all are async.  Imagine case like getFormData completed before other calls and you are checking if formdata has last option of first dropdown selected. check may fail as firstDropDownData itself will be empty array